# vertical line between the cells

Tags: tables

could someone kindly help me out how to solve this problem by completing the vertical line between the cells.

Regards

[image]

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
%\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \centering
  \caption{\textsc{Discrete Probability Distribution of Wind and Solar Resources, and Load}}
    \begin{tabular}{cc | cc | cc}
 \hlinewd{1.5pt}
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} \multicolumn{2}{c | }{\textbf{Solar}} & \multicolumn{2}{| c | }{\textbf{Wind }} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Load}} \\
 \hlinewd{1.5pt}
    \% of deviation      & Probability  & \% of deviation          & Probability     & \% of deviation           & Probability \\
        $e_{PV}$ & $\rho_{PV}$  &  $e_{W}$ &   $\rho_{W}$    &  $e_{L}$     & $\rho_{L}$ \\
 \hlinewd{1.5pt}
    -2.5 & 0.2 & -5    & 0.05 & -5    & 0.05 \\
         0 & 0.6 & -2.5 & 0.1   & -2.5 & 0.15 \\
      2.5 & 0.2 & 0      & 0.7   & 0      & 0.6 \\
         - & -    & 2.5    & 0.1   & 2.5  & 0.15 \\
          - & -    & 5      & 0.05 & 5     & 0.05 \\
 \hlinewd{1.5pt}
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab4.1}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: No, please add the code to your table post above ;-)

Comment: The `booktabs` package recommends the following: "Never, ever use vertical rules". Have you considered redesigning your table with just horizontal lines?

Comment: Please post a ***complete*** example as the link posted above describes. Your current code cannot be compiled as is and uses non-standard commands which might come from anywhere (so it cannot even be completed without figuring out where those commands are from or how they should be defined).

Comment: Or just use `booktabs` if you want a professional-looking table, as suggested above.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt following the guidelines of [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for professional tables and [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for alignment of the numerical data.

Note that braces (`{...}`) are used to escape the contents of cells that do not contain numbers to be aligned. `\multicolumn` also serves this purpose for those cells.

Allowing space for the minus sign in the alignment is a matter of personal taste. I did not leave room for it (`table-format=1.2` means a number with one digit before and two digits after the decimal separator), but you could leave room for it with `table-format=-1.1`.

I've also used `*{<num-repeat>}{<col-spec>}` to avoid repetition by repeating `<col-spec>` `<num-repeat>` times in the `tabular`'s preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
  *{2}{S[table-format=1.1]} 
  *{2}{S[table-format=1.1]S[table-format=1.2]}
}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Solar} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wind} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Load} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-2}          \cmidrule(lr){3-4}         \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
  {\% of deviation} & {Probability} & 
    {\% of deviation} & {Probability} & 
    {\% of deviation} & {Probability} \\
  {$e_{PV}$} & {$\rho_{PV}$} & 
    {$e_{W}$} & {$\rho_{W}$} & 
    {$e_{L}$} & {$\rho_{L}$} \\
  \midrule
   -2.5 &   0.2 & -5.0 & 0.05 & -5.0 & 0.05 \\
    0.0 &   0.6 & -2.5 & 0.10 & -2.5 & 0.15 \\
    2.5 &   0.2 &  0.0 & 0.70 &  0.0 & 0.60 \\
  {---} & {---} &  2.5 & 0.10 &  2.5 & 0.15 \\
  {---} & {---} &  5.0 & 0.05 &  5.0 & 0.05 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The table is too wide for the standard `article` class, but I have no idea what class or margin settings you are using. I can help more with this if you provide that information.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to use vertical rules compatible with your horizontal rules, you should try `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (in that environment, the vertical rules are also compatible with the rules of `booktabs` --- even though this is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs` to use vertical rules).

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}
 \usepackage{geometry}

 \makeatletter
 \def\hlinewd#1{%
 \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
 \futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline} 
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
 \centering
 \caption{\textsc{Discrete Probability Distribution of Wind and Solar Resources, and Load}}
 \begin{NiceTabular}{cc | cc | cc}[colortbl-like]
 \hlinewd{1.5pt}
 \RowStyle{\bfseries}
 \rowcolor[gray]{.9} \Block{1-2}{Solar} && \Block{1-2}{Wind} && \Block{1-2}{Load} \\
 \hlinewd{1.5pt}
 \% of deviation & Probability & \% of deviation & Probability & \% of deviation & Probability \\
 $e_{PV}$ & $\rho_{PV}$  &  $e_{W}$ &   $\rho_{W}$    &  $e_{L}$     & $\rho_{L}$ \\
 \hlinewd{1.5pt}
 -2.5  & 0.2  & -5   & 0.05 & -5   & 0.05 \\
     0 & 0.6  & -2.5 & 0.1  & -2.5 & 0.15 \\
   2.5 & 0.2  & 0    & 0.7  & 0    & 0.6 \\
     - & -    & 2.5  & 0.1  & 2.5  & 0.15 \\
     - & -    & 5    & 0.05 & 5    & 0.05 \\
 \hlinewd{1.5pt}
 \end{NiceTabular}
 \label{tab4.1}
 \end{table}
     
 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a dummy row before your first row:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc|cc}
\hlinewd{1.5pt}
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} & & & & & \\[-10pt]
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Solar}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}
{\textbf{Wind}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Load}} \\
\hlinewd{1.5pt}
```

where the `[-10pt]` can be adjusted to suit your taste.  Tell me if it works.